# Case comments and case custom buttons in the Lightning environment

Tags: lightning, custom-button, case, lightning-experience, casefeed

I have a requirement where I want to enable case comments in the Lightning environment along with the custom buttons on the case. I have created a lightning quick-action for the custom button. My problem is whenever I add that quick action it comes under feed section. I want it on the button panel similar to standard buttons Please refer screenshot.

1. How to add a quick action in place of action buttons?
2. Is it possible to remove create new text box and button which SF is inserting by default on custom buttons?
3. How can I enable case comments without feed and view those in the lightning environment?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not possible (for all objects) - these are the `Activity` buttons and they are more like tabs in LEX and will stay in the `Activities` standard component - you should see it in the app builder:

[image]

2. Again - this is the `Activities` standard component - you cannot change it so you cannot remove the `create new` textbox and the `add` button.
3. `Case Comments` is a related object list - you can put it wherever you want with the app builder - just drag the `Related List` component and then select the object:
   [image]